# Adjust graph to first value of the series and not 0 in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph that X axis goes from 0 to 100, 5 by 5. I pass a serie that most of the times doesn't fill 0 or 100, one time probably is 20-60, others 35-75, etc.

```
        var ageOptions = {
            yAxis: {gridLineWidth: 0,labels: "",title: ""},
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['0', '5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50', '55', '60', '65', '70', '75', '80', '85', '90', '95', '100'],
                lineColor: 'transparent',tickColor: 'transparent',labels: {formatter: function(){if (this.isFirst || this.isLast) {return this.value;} else {return '';}}}
            },
            tooltip: {formatter: function() {return this.x;}},
            series: [{lineWidth: 4,marker: {radius: 4},data: data.distribution.data}]
        };
```

What I want is to not have 0 values from 0 to 20 (where the first Y axis point is setted) and not end on 100 if it only goes to 75.

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by first calculating the min and max values of the series, then calling xaxis.setExtremes(min,max) method.

Highcharts example (http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/9/)